# Loop control inside void function keeps looping

Tags: c++, function, loops, boolean, void

```
void getDay() {
    bool repeat;
    do
    {
        cout << "Enter the day code (first 2 letters): ";
        cin >> weekDay1;
        cin >> weekDay2;
        weekDay1 = toupper(weekDay1);
        weekDay2 = toupper(weekDay2);
            
        switch (weekDay1)
            {
                case 'M':
                    break;
                case 'T':
                    break;
                case 'W':
                    break;
                case 'F':
                    break;
                case 'S':
                    break;
                default:
                    cout << "Invalid input. Please try again.\n";
                    repeat = true;
                break;
            }
            
        switch (weekDay2) 
            {
                case 'O':
                    break;
                case 'U':
                    break;
                case 'E':
                    break;
                case 'H':
                    break;
                case 'R':
                    break;
                case 'A':
                    break;
                default:
                    cout << "Invalid input. Please try again.\n";
                    repeat = true;
                break;
            }
    
    }while (repeat == true);
        
        return;
}
```

I need this function to run once, and loop if the input is not one of the accepted characters. I'm trying to prevent any bad input, but it loops infinitely if the input entered on the initial run is not accepted. It works fine if the input is good on the first run, but I keep getting run-time errors for not initializing bools and I need some help adjusting this control.

Comment: `repeat = false` inside `do`?

Comment: That's probably because you aren't assigning a value to `repeat` when you declare it, which results in it containing garbage data that, when converted to `bool`, generally results in a value of `true`. Try `bool repeat = false;` instead and you'll avoid this problem.

Comment: repeat inside of do causes repeat to not be declared for the while condition. and bool repeat = false leads to the same problem of an infinite loop.

Comment: When would `repeat` ever become false if you do not ever set it to false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition in the while loop is always `true` because you never set it to `false` in its body. You can do something like this:

```cpp
void getDay() {
  // Initializing while declaring is a good practice.
  bool repeat = false;

  do {
    .
    .
    repeat = false;
    .
    switch(...) {
      ...
    }
  } while (repeat);
}
```

Now, `repeat = true` is only called if one of the switch statements invokes `default`.